# asp.net / i want to clear the textfield history

Tags: asp.net, textfield

I just want every time I press in textbox I don't want let see any history that I typed before thank u ex:  please the imag down 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAizf.png)

Comment: try window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("yourTextboxId").name = "txt"+ Math.random();
}

Comment: <asp:TextBox Runat="server" ID="TextBox1" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `AutoCompleteType` property of the textbox to *Disabled*

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```